# Help with extracting value in a string with PHP

Tags: php, string

Anyone could tell me if it's possible in PHP to get the value "www.businessweek.com" from the following string:

```
[url=http://s.tt/11MXX]
[img]http://i.curate.us/img/a67f63e06f32291b79198e33de6f2d8f?offset=0&size=450&stamp=1294861758[/img]
[/url]Clipped from: [url=http://s.tt/11MXX]www.businessweek.com[/url]
([url=http://curate.us/11MXX+]share this clip[/url])
```

It's the curateus BB code version...I've made some testing and could also be without the "www".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/\[url=.*?\](.*?)\[\/url\]/i', $data, $matches);
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/82x6TeV9bM

Comment: Sorry: Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash at http://ideone.com/kKxjM